# GNU Screen: Combining split-regions and full-screen sessions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu-screen, console

Let's say I have three sessions: 0, 1 and 2

I'm on session 0 and I press CTRL-A S to split the screen. Then I select session 1 for the bottom split region, while 0 is in the upper.

Can I switch to session 2 and have it display in full-screen while 0 and 1 remain split? If I CTRL-A n to other sessions in a split screen it only changes the split-region. I want some sessions to be full-screen though.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The terminal is split into pains and *windows* (not sessions) are shown in each pane.  With `screen` you are not able to change quickly between unsplit and split.  You could probably set up some macros to push the necessary operations.

`tmux` might be able to do this for you, but I've never spent much time with it.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Screen does the splitting "above" the organisation of individual screens. So, no.

However, you can nest screen sessions. This is one reason for the `-m` and `-e` options. You can nest in either direction (or even both), but the hotkey usage can get tricky.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04 using GNU Screen version `4.08.00 (GNU) 05-Feb-20`, I am able to get the OP's desired behavior using the following. You can add it to your `~/.screenrc` (may require some tweaking; I don't use it this way) or save it somewhere and then use it by invoking screen as follows:

`screen -c /path/to/file -S session_name`

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Loads a multi-pane layout with easy access to terminal + vim editor w/bottom terminal
#
# 0 - Bash prompt
# 1 - Vim (focused)
# 2 - Bash prompt
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Create new layout with bash prompt
layout new shell
layout title shells
layout select shell
screen -t shell bash

# Create new layout with vim + bottom terminal
layout new editor
layout title editor
layout select editor
# Open vim in
screen -t vim bash -c 'vim; bash'

focus

# Horizontal split
split

# Move to bottom split
focus down

# Create bash shell in bottom split
select 1
screen -t term bash

# Give vim bash shell a little less vertical space
resize -v -15

# Move focus back up to vim
focus up
```

The key is using layouts. You can [read more about them here](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Layout), but the gist of it is you use layouts to contain collections of windows and then you switch between layouts vs. windows for the type of behavior that you'd like. That being the case, I've added the following to my `.screenrc` to simplify layout switching:

```
# Creates a default layout of 0, which makes the user's sessions start
# numbering at 1, which makes for easier switching
# (it also saves your layout to 'default' by default)
layout save default

# Create new layout with shell prompt when creating a new window
bind c eval 'layout new' screen

# Switch between layouts with Alt+Number
bindkey "^[0" layout select 0
bindkey "^[1" layout select 1
bindkey "^[2" layout select 2
bindkey "^[3" layout select 3
bindkey "^[4" layout select 4
bindkey "^[5" layout select 5
bindkey "^[6" layout select 6
bindkey "^[7" layout select 7
bindkey "^[8" layout select 8
bindkey "^[9" layout select 9

# Switch to previous layout
bind , layout prev

# Switch to next layout
bind . layout next

# Show all layouts
bind s layout show
```

Note: All of the above are cobbled together from hours of researching, reviewing blog posts, etc., so I don't claim credit for anything other than managing to compile together a solution that works for me :)